# How to read new text files when spark is already running?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I am using spark 2 to read data from HDFS and to treat them.
In order to import my data from HDFS, I use the following:

```
JavaRDD<String> msg= spark.read().textFile("hdfs://myfolder/*").javaRDD();
```

But I wonder if spark reads new text files created after I started to run spark.

IF it is not the case, can you tell me how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the Spark job starts to run, it won't read new files after that. What are you trying to do? Do you want to monitor HDFS and process new files? If so, you can try [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)

Comment: Actually, I am building a lambda architecture. For the batch layer, I want to use HDFS and spark. However, I read input data from a kafka server and when there is a new data, I insert this new data in hdfs in order to be batch processed.

Comment: Or do I have to run periodically my code to read and process new data from hdfs. And when it is done, I re-run my code and so on ?

Comment: Yes. But Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming makes such job easiler

Answer (score 1):

Do you think streaming api will work for you? It can monitor directory for new files and continue to process them as they come if all data is not available initially.

From http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers

"For reading data from files on any file system compatible with the HDFS API (that is, HDFS, S3, NFS, etc.), a DStream can be created as: sample code

**Spark Streaming will monitor the directory dataDirectory and process any files created in that directory** (files written in nested directories not supported). Note that

- The files must have the same data format.
- The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory.
- Once moved, the files must not be changed. So if the files are being continuously appended, the new data will not be read.
  "

Comment: Ok thanks for the link and explanation. However, when I studied the lambda architecture, it is said that Apache Saprk is used for the batch layer and not Spark Streaming which is used for the streaming layer (what I did).

Comment: If you need to process all data available in HDFS, as you correctly said, you need to re-run it. E.g. re-training machine learning model after getting new data. Hope that helps.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to know (potentially in Java) what are the new files added ?